# crash after accessing photo library using UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

I am having troubles with accessing Photo Library when the button is tapped. Just as usual I am asking if it is accessible. Below is my code

```
@IBAction func photoLibraryButtonTapped(sender: UIButton) {

        if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary) {
            let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
            imagePicker.delegate = self
            imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary
            imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
            self.presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
```

And here is what Xcode says:

```
2016-08-08 23:05:11.209 Auyrma[1799:20237892] -[UIViewController photoLibraryButtonTapped:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fd3e9d39ed0
2016-08-08 23:05:11.214 Auyrma[1799:20237892] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIViewController photoLibraryButtonTapped:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fd3e9d39ed0'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000113fdcd85 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000113a50deb objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000113fe5d3d -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000113f2bcfa ___forwarding___ + 970
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000113f2b8a8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   UIKit                               0x00000001124d6a8d -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 92
    6   UIKit                               0x0000000112649e67 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67
    7   UIKit                               0x000000011264a143 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 327
    8   UIKit                               0x0000000112649263 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 601
    9   UIKit                               0x000000011254999f -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 835
    10  UIKit                               0x000000011254a6d4 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 865
    11  UIKit                               0x00000001124f5dc6 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 263
    12  UIKit                               0x00000001124cf553 _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 6660
    13  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000113f02301 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000113ef822c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000113ef76e3 __CFRunLoopRun + 867
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000113ef70f8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 488
    17  GraphicsServices                    0x00000001164bcad2 GSEventRunModal + 161
    18  UIKit                               0x00000001124d4f09 UIApplicationMain + 171
    19  Auyrma                              0x000000010e1c2d82 main + 114
    20  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000114e8492d start + 1
    21  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: Did you check if the IBAction is connected properly to a button ? OR where do you call the method photoLibraryButtonTapped?

Comment: @teja yeap, double checked. everything is ok there

Comment: Have you set the class to your `UIViewController` in IB?

Comment: @adil yeap, double checked that too

Comment: How do you instantiate the class? And WHat is your current class name ?

Comment: @teja class name is ChallengeViewController, everything ok there too, cause when I open assistant editor it shows right class. the class is cocoa touch class which is UIViewController

Comment: When you right click on the button, does it show only one selector for touch-up-inside, and that is linking to your desired ViewController?

Comment: the error is saying that photoLibraryButtonTapped is called on a UIVIEwCOntroller class. But in real time, that method is declared in the ChallengeViewController. Please double check that the class name is set to ChallengeViewController in IB and in code.

Comment: thank you, guys! I've solved my problem

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1.Please check target of your view controller and storyboard files should be in same target.
2.select your xib and remove your class which is mapped to that storyboard and map it back and press enter once you paste your class your nib name keep same for testing.
3.If this button is loading form custom view to view controller need to check that custom views are added to right target and  re-map touch up inside with ibaction again.

This is what I could figure it out by see your conversations.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem this way:

1. Open up the Utilites
2. Open the Identity Inspector
3. Provide the class name again (however it was there already)

It seems like it was a bug of Xcode...